# What fonts are supported by Salesforce PDF generation?

Tags: pdf-generation, apex-code

I'm generating a pdf using a VisualForce page with the renderAs param set to pdf. I'm wishing for more fonts even though others have [complained there are few](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&cnid=10094848). Does anyone know of additional fonts that work with Salesforce pdf generation?

So far I've only found five fonts that work (serif, sans-serif, monospace, courier, and arial unicode ms) by testing with a simple VisualForce page like this:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <h2>Standard Font Families</h2>
    <p style="font-family: serif;">Serif</p>    
    <p style="font-family: sans-serif;">Sans-serif</p>
    <p style="font-family: monospace;">Monospace</p>    

    <h2>Additional Fonts (wishing for more)</h2>
    <p style="font-family: Courier;">Courier!</p>    
    <p style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">Arial Unicode MS!</p>

    <h2>Missing Fonts</h2>
    <p style="font-family: Arial;">Arial</p>
    <p style="font-family: Helvetica;">Helvetica</p>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana;">Verdana</p>
    <p style="font-family: Georgia;">Georgia</p>
    <p style="font-family: Times;">Times</p>
    <p style="font-family: Times New Roman;">Times New Roman</p>
    <p style="font-family: Consolas;">Consolas</p>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I just ran through all the fonts on this [common fonts page](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) and came up empty.

Comment: Ran through the [14 iText base fonts](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts)...no joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is it for now:

- Serif
- Sans-serif
- Monospace
- Courier
- Arial Unicode MS